# Действия с вектором

Tags: c++

Доброго времени суток.

Какая разница между этими операциями, если результат один и тот же? Или это создано для увеличения функционала и гибкости?

```
#include<iostream>
#inclube<vector>
void main(){
vector<int>vecMyVector(5,1);             
vecMyVector.insert(vecMyVector.end(),3); //1
vecMyVector.push_back(4);                //2
vecMyVector.emplace_back(5);             //3
for(int i=0;i<vecMyVector.size();i++)
{
cout<<vecMyVector[i]<<" "; 
 } 
}
```

И на эту сроку у меня компилятор (VS 2010) ругается почему-то.

```
copy(vecMyVector.begin(),vecMyVector.end(),ostream_iterator<int>(cout," "));
```

Выдает такие ошибки:

```
 error C2065: 'ostream_iterator' : undeclared identifier
 еrror C2062: type 'int' unexpected
```

В чем может быть трабл?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну вообще-то `insert` и `push_back` - это просто две разных функции с разным (хоть и схожим) назначением, для которых вы "подогнали" ситуации, в которых они действуют в общем-то аналогично. То, что функцию insert можно вызывать, передавая ей в качестве первого параметра итератор, указывающий на конец вектора, не означает, что сама insert аналогична функции push_back. Что же касается emplace_back, то ее отличие от push_back кроется в целях оптимизации производительности

Comment: Значит, для удобства и многозадачности они необходимы?

Comment: эмм..при чем здесь многозадачность?

Comment: Не забудьте еще единообразие разных контейнеров, и будет полноценный ответ)